# How to permanently disable Windows 11 upgrade nag screen?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, adware

I occasionally get full screen ads about my computer being eligible for a Windows 11 upgrade, which looks something like this
[image]

Hardwarewise the computer probably is capable of running Windows 11. Apparently this ad cannot be disabled by a single click anymore (it just goes to another full page nag screen). I have drivers and other software running on this computer which might possibly get disrupted by an OS change (do not want to take any chance on that). I am worried that I might accidently click on something other than decline upgrade at some point.

**Is there a way to permanently disable the full page nag screen for Windows 11 that appears when turning the computer on ?**

I am running
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 22H2
OS build    19045.3448
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19044.1000.0
with everything up to date.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of online tips to stop the nag screens. In my opinion, the safest is to add [a Policies value](https://allthings.how/how-to-stop-windows-11-update-from-installing-on-your-windows-10-pc/) so that Windows 10 updates (what's left of them, about a year, at this writing) can continue, but update to Windows 11 is blocked.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *rege* and select *Regedit*.
- Open to the following key, e.g., by pasting it into the *Regedit* navigation bar. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate`.

  If the key `WindowsUpdate` does not exist in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows`, create it.
- Right-click the right pane and select *New > ‘DWORD (32-bit) Value*. Set its  name to `TargetReleaseVersion`.
- Double-click it and set its value to `1`.
- Right-click the right pane and select *New > Sting Value*. Set its name to `ProductVersion`.
- Double-click it and set its value to `Windows 10`.

*Caveat*: [Windows 10 EOL is Oct 14, 2025](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-10-home-and-pro). Organizations can buy Extended Security Updates, but pricing and minimum quantity make this difficult for the individual. For reasons of security, consider testing and upgrading to Windows 11.

If hardware cannot accommodate Windows 11 requirements, consider testing another OS, such as Linux. Yes, you've gone to some effort to get that Windows 10 system working using specific drivers. The good new is you can test Linux from USB without having to install it, or install it *inside* Windows 10 in a virtual machine, or install it dual boot, so you can  test it, add drivers, and create an OS that works for your use.

Comment: This should work until the End of Support for Windows 22H2, it’s entirely possible, this policy will not be respected in the future provided the system supports Windows 11.

Comment: @Ramhound, agreed, but AFAIK, there will be no upgrade of *Windows 10* past 22H2, *ergo* the Registry setting will not need to be changed. However, it seems the OP will be stuck with a "deprecated" OS, and should think of some way to move beyond that stop-gap measure.

Comment: I am suggesting that after 22H2 is no longer supported, despite the group policy preventing the upgrade to whatever is after Windows 11 22H2 in a year, Windows might resume the prompts to upgrade. If that happens there will no doubt be a way to stop those future prompts